# How to use mobile jQuery Asychronous API with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I want to add the angular tags for this login function to shift the code from mobile Jquery to Angularjs. Any suggestion guys?

```
this.login = function(login, password, cb){
    this.execute('user/login', {email: login, password: password}, cb);
};

this.logout = function(cb){
    this.execute('user/logout', {}, cb);
}

this.userGet = function(email, cb, fcb){
    this.execute('user/get_user', {email: email}, cb, fcb);
}

// code for the login for a web application
```

Comment: What is the expected result? What have you done so far?

Comment: Check out a tutorial to get a basic understanding about angular, and the docs for the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for your ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

To convert an asychronous API that uses callbacks to an Angular promise:

```
/*
this.login = function(login, password, cb){
    this.execute('user/login', {email: login, password: password}, cb);
};
*/

function loginPromise(login, password) {
    var future = $q.defer();
    this.execute('user/login',
                 {email: login, password: password},
                 future.resolve
    );
    return future.promise;
}
```

By creating a $q service promise from the asynchronous API, any changes to scope will be integrated with the AngularJS framework digest cycle.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).